# React Native: TypeError: interpolateNode is not a function

Tags: react-native, testing, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to update my fork of `React Navigation Drawer` to update React Native and Reanimated versions of it. I have one failing test and it is giving me following error:

> TypeError: interpolateNode is not a
> function at Drawer.interpolateNode [as render] (/drawer/src/views/Drawer.tsx:518:16)

My Reanimated version is `2.2.3`. I have checked the node_modules folder and the function is there and exported correctly. But in test it is failing.
I have checked all the similar issues on the original repository and here but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Can someone give me a hint?

Here is the link of my fork: https://github.com/olcayertas/drawer/pull/1